# Does utilizing exhaust energy to supercharge ("turbocharging") increase the thermal efficiency of a gasoline internal combustion engine?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, energy-efficiency

The work done by a turbocharger increases the inlet charge without much of a burden to the exhaust flow.  This increases the amount of air (and fuel) that flows into the engine. How does this affect work done for a given amount of fuel consumed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the turbo-compressor increase the efficiency of car engine?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11000/does-the-turbo-compressor-increase-the-efficiency-of-car-engine)

Comment: Before asking my question, I had read the referenced post, and hesitated to do so for that reason.  However, after reading it and previously many related discussions on other sites, I felt that the question should be asked and categorized differently, which would yield more data.

Comment: Any thermodynamics textbook will show how this is calculated... I still use Rogers & Mayhew...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, turbocharging improves both the volumetric and thermal efficiency.

But as most drivers tend to use the power that does not always translate to an improved fuel consumption.

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated and depends on application and demands such as emissions restrictions and required throttle response, but generally, figure on about a 2 percentile improvement with a turbo. An example would be going from 34% to 36% thermal efficiency by adding a turbo.

You can see this for yourself if you look at the BSFC fuel maps of a family of engines that include turbo and normally aspirated versions.